# writing data from c++ to csv

Tags: c++, csv

I am new to programming in c++. I want to write some data to a csv file. 
here's my code that tries to do that but it only writes 1 variable (population) in the column 
not the other one (year).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    / data generation/

ofstream USPopulation;
USPopulation.open("D:\\2.csv");
USPopulation << "Population,Year" << endl;
int year = 1790;
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
{
    USPopulation << population[index], year;  / this only writes the population values /
    USPopulation << endl;
    year += 1;
}

USPopulation.close();
return 0;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why it's just writing the population values and not years to the file?
Thanks!

Comment: `, year;` <=== What do you intend to do this??

Comment: Try `<<` operator: `USPopulation << population[index] << year;`. Os, as you want a CSV file `USPopulation << population[index] << "," << year << std::endl`

Answer (score 5):

You are using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) here:

```
USPopulation << population[index], year;
//                               ^
```

The effect is to evaluate

```
USPopulation << population[index]
```

and discard the result, then evaluate and return

```
year
```

So, you need something like

```
USPopulation << population[index] << "," << year;
```

assuming you want the separator to be a single `,`.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
USPopulation << population[index] << "," << year;
```

---

**Edit:** You are *by chance* using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) (it's better it's not an operator here to make you be aware of this :)):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using it like this code ?

```
USPopulation << population[index] << ", " << year;
```

Comment: B'coz OP doesn't know this